# How can I make an " if " statement true using a number in-between 2 numbers? C++

Tags: c++

In my opinion I feel like many people are confused about this question. What I want to do is ask the user for a number and if it is between 0 - 17, the output I would want it to be is:

```
Too Young
```

And if it is 18 - 42, the output should be:

```
Adult
```

And if it's 43 and over to be:

```
Senior
```

All while using the switch statement

Here is the code I used:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    cin >> age;
    if (age <= 16) {
        cout <<"Too young";
    }
    if (age <= 42) {
        cout << "Adult";
    }
    if (age <= 70) {
        cout << "Senior";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of my code is:

```
Too YoungAdultSenior
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Why do you think a `switch` statement is appropriate to this task?

Comment: You might want to look up the keyword `else`.

Comment: `if (age >=17 && age <= 42)` and `if (age >=43 && age <= 70)`.

Comment: What if age is over 70?

Comment: 15 is < 16. It is also < 42. It is also < 70.

Comment: even not mentioning about the missing `else`s, your logic is still flawed: 17 is supposed to be "too young" but it is not in your code.

Answer (score 6):

Replace your code with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    cin >> age;
    if (age <= 17) {
        cout <<"Too young";
    } else if (age <= 42) {
        cout << "Adult";
    } else {
        cout << "Senior";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That isn't quite the same. The last clause should be `else if (age <= 70) {`, since the original code doesn't try to output anything for ages above 70 (it's `<= 70`, not `>= 70`).

Comment: It shouldn't be the same as the original code. The instructions state `And if it's 43 and over to be: "Senior"`. The final else should be sufficient for that.

Comment: Sorry about that @Olathe I accidentally put " < = 70 ". That was my fault.

Comment: You might also want to consider checking out the website: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Comment: @MiguelNunez I don't think switch statement could work here

Comment: (age <=16) should be (age<=17) according to the question.

Answer (score 1):

To check if something is 2 conditions at the same time, use the `&&` operator, which means `and` and checks for two conditions being true either side. Example for age between `44 and 56`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int age=55;
    if ((age>=44) && (age <= 56))
    {
       std::cout << "YAY!!!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In C++11 - instead of `&&`, you can use `and` keyword.

Comment: The code works, but when I try to use " cin >> age; " it says there is any error. Why?

Comment: @MiguelNunez Do you have `int age;` above `cin >> age;`?

Comment: You must add 'std::cin>>age;' In his code, Arnav has not used the statement 'using namespace std;'

Comment: @Olathe Yes I did do that

Comment: @Vaibhav Bajaj Can I still do it with " using namespace std; "? If not, please tell me why. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you can do it with that statement. In that case, simply remove 'std::' from all other statements.

Comment: I have added my answer to that query below: `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    cin >> age;
    if ((age>=44) && (age <= 56))
    {
       cout << "YAY!!!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}`

Comment: Hey Miguel, why do you find it confusing? Is it because of the statement `using namespace std;` or because of the bad formatting? If it is bad formatting, I can submit a separate answer that has better formatting. Answers are not meant to be submitted in comments

Comment: Use the charachter ` around what you wish to format.

Answer (score 1):

In the above answer, if you wish to use `using namespace std;`, simply use this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    cin >> age;
    if ((age>=44) && (age <= 56))
    {
       cout << "YAY!!!\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer using the statement `using namespace std;`. Sorry Arnav, I did not wish to copy.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would do it with a `switch` statement btw:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int age;
    cin >> age;

    switch (age) {
        case 0: case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5: case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: case 10: case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15: case 16: case 17:
            cout << "Too young\n";
            break;
        case 18: case 19: case 20: case 21: case 22: case 23: case 24: case 25: case 26: case 27: case 28: case 29: case 30: case 31: case 32: case 33: case 34: case 35: case 36: case 37: case 38: case 39: case 40:
            cout << "Adult\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Senior\n";

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way:-

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    cin >> age;
    if (age < 18 && age >=0) {
        cout <<"Too young";
    } else if (age >= 18 && age <= 42) {
        cout << "Adult";
    } else if(age > 42)
        cout << "Senior";
    }

    return 0;
}
```